# SVG edge smoothing/anti-alias after applying fedisplacementmap filter

Tags: svg, filter

FeDisplacementMap filter is giving me jagged/pixelated edges. I have a rectangular box filled with horizontal B&W striped pattern. I m curving the rectangle with fedisplacementmap according to my requirement. But all the edges are getting pixaleted/jagged. I have tried fegussionblur, convolvematrix with edge detection, still no success, any help will be appreciated.

Problem Link : http://www.avisone.com/TEST.svg

Should be like this : http://www.avisone.com/result.png

---

### Here is my filter

```
<filter id="f3" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="200%" filterRes="1600">
<feImage xlink:href="img/bubble.png" result="Map" y="0.133844" width="0.36074" height="0.1"/>
<feDisplacementMap in2="Map" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" in="SourceGraphic"  yChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" scale="0.00">
<animate attributeName="scale" dur="10s" values="0.00;0.12;0.00"  repeatCount="indefinite"/></feDisplacementMap>
  <!-- tried but result not good-->
<!--feGaussianBlur in="DDD" stdDeviation="0.9" result="blur" />
  <feMerge>        
    <feMergeNode in="DDD"/>
    <feMergeNode in="blur"/>
  </feMerge-->   
</filter>
```

---

Comment: Can you show the resulting image?

Comment: A working example showing the aliasing would be preferred.  Reduce the work people have to do and the more likely you are to get an answer.